# How to link a static libary in cmake created from another directory?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following simplified directory structure for my cmake project

```
- project/
  - src/
    - network/
      - network.hpp
      - network.cpp
      - CMakeLists.txt
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - test/
    - network_test.cpp
    - CMakeLists.txt
- CMakeLists.txt
```

In `project/src/network/CMakeLists.txt`, the `network` static libary is built

```
add_library(network STATIC "")
target_sources(network
        PUBLIC
        network.hpp
        PRIVATE
        network.cpp)
target_include_directories(network PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(network PRIVATE pthread)
target_link_libraries(network PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL)
```

In `project/test/network_test.cpp`, I need to link against the network library, however, since the target network is from another directory, even though the following cannot successfully link `network_cpp` against `network`.

Top level CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(Argon)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_subdirectory(src)

add_subdirectory(test)
```

src/network/CMakeList.txt

```
add_library(network STATIC "")
target_sources(network
        PUBLIC
        network.hpp
        PRIVATE
        network.cpp)
target_include_directories(network PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(network PRIVATE pthread)
target_link_libraries(network PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL)
```

test/network_test/CMakeList.txt

```
add_executable(network_test network_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(network_test PRIVATE GTest::GTest)
target_link_libraries(network_test PRIVATE network)
enable_testing()
add_test(NAME google_test
        COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:network_test>)
```

The error produced is the following:

```
usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/network_test.dir/network_test.cpp.o: in function `network_cpp_get_HEAD_does_not_throw_Test::TestBody()':
/home/bill/CLionProjects/Argon/test/network/network_test.cpp:8: undefined reference to `Argon::network::get_HEAD(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::asio::io_context&)'
```

What is the solution to this? Or is my project structure flawed?

Comment: Please add all `CMakeLists.txt` files. There is no reason why that shouldn't work.

Comment: Your code actually **links** with the library. (You have corresponding `target_link_libraries` call and the linker aren't complain that it cannot find the library). The reason of "undefined reference" is somewhere else, and cannot be deduced from the information you provided.

Comment: Thank you Tsyvarev! I have since realized my I called the function `get_HEAD` but the function is not actually implemented in the source file due to another function with a similar name being declared in the header as well.